# Android App Name Per Build Type AND Flavour

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My application is having multiple **build types** and **flavours** gradle.

```
buildTypes {
    release {}
    test {}
    debug {}
}
productFlavors {
    europe {}
    asia {}
}
```

How can I name the app according to the combination of build type and flavor?

Example:
Flavour **europe** will have app name **AppEurope**
BuildType **test** will add "**Test**" suffix behind the app name, **AppEuropeTest**

Comment: [This question has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19830972/2823516)

Comment: I'm looking for Build Type and Flavour combination, not just Flavour.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same problem within my watch face and tried to combine flavor dependent application names with build type dependent application label values. I ended up doing it as follows:

1. Use manifestPlaceholder in the build.gradle to inject buildType specific string resource links:

In the build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel: "@string/app_name"]
  }
  debug {
     manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel: "@string/app_name_dev" ]
  }
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
   [..]
   android:label="${applicationLabel}">
```

In the strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Classic &amp; Essential</string>
  <string name="app_name_dev">Classic &amp; Essential (DEV)</string>
</resources>
```

2. Use flavor specific versions of string.xml resource files overriding the values for the flavor.

I also described this in one of my blog posts:
https://www.journal.deviantdev.com/android-build-type-app-name-label/

Comment: You should change the Launcher's activity label as well.

Comment: Thanks, this answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions has been answered here -

[How to change app name per Gradle build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type)

> Create separate versions of string.xml for each build type for all
>   the flavours.

There is a a sample project here.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloBuildType

> Edit 1

```
android.sourceSets.europe {
    res.srcDirs = ['flavor_resources/europe/res']
}

android.sourceSets.europe.debug {
    res.srcDirs = ['flavor_resources/europe/debug/res']
}
```

Comment: I'm not just looking for app naming for "Build Types", but "BuildTypes AND Flavours"

Answer (score 0):

[Related link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19830972/2823516) shows how to do this for flavors, and the concept is identical when expanding to include build types - we can think of both flavors and build types as combining to create "variants", and we can configure variants as easily as the flavors that make them.

### Assume:

You have these build types:

- release
- test
- debug

You have these flavors:

- europe
- asia

You have a default `app_name` string resource declared in the normal place

- `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

  ```
    <string name="app_name">App</string>
  ```

### Manifest file:

There is no need for manifest placeholders in this simple case. If your case requires, you can configure them as per the other answers.

Simply use `app_name` in the manifest directly. Trust that the changes you make for the variants will reflect correctly.

e.g.

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    etc...
```

### Different names for variants:

As standard, gradle allows for resource files to be declared at in variant source folders (like the flavor or build type source folders) and these will automatically override the defaults.

There is no need for source sets in this simple case.

Simply add a new `strings.xml` file for each variant, redefining the `app_name` to match that variant.

e.g. For the Europe Test build, add your file at the variant folder named `europeTest`, and override the name:

- `src/europeTest/res/values/strings.xml`

  ```
    <string name="app_name">AppEuropeTest</string>
  ```

Different variants will also get their own override strings files as required.

### App name suffix per flavor:

With app ID, each flavor can be configured to add a bit to the app ID.

This is not currently possible with the normal build system, so you cannot currently configure the `test` build to append the name "Test" to the main name, and then configure the `europe` flavor to append "Europe".

That would be really nice, but is not supported natively.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786248/383414) suggests a library that you can use for an alternative way of combining the app names, and could probably be used to make a more logical naming system, especially with more flavor dimensions (similar to how one would do it for application ID).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Make your existing application module to a library module and then create two new application modules named EuropeApp and AsiaApp.

Now, you'll see those two (eaurope and asia apps) in app selection drop down.

for each of these two application modules, add your three build Types(release, test, debug). then for each build type, add a manifest placeholder for the app name.

And make sure you create an empty activity for each of the application module and extend it to the MainActivity (or which ever the launcher activity is) from library module.

This type of project structure gives you maximum benefits.